# ng-submit not working correctly with enter key

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to AngularJS and now facing the following problem.

Inserting new items works well by clicking the submit button, but doesn't work when I hit the Enter button. With enter the $scope.newQueryInput is undefined.

Also with the first enter, I get a new item inserted (with an empty string). With the second hit nothing is happening, which should be the expected behaviour for the first hit too.

```
<!--HTML part-->
<ul ng-controller="QueryCtrl">
    <li ng-repeat="query in queries">
        <i class="fa fa-trash onhover alignleft" title="delete query" ng-click="removeQuery($index)"></i>
        <a href="#">{{query.keyword}}</a>
    </li>
    <li class="addnew">
        <form ng-submit="addQuery()" action="">
            <input type="text" ng-model="newQueryInput" placeholder="Add new query"/>
            <input type="submit" />
        </form>
    </li>
</ul>


// script.js
var App = angular.module('App', []);
function QueryCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.queries = queries;
    $scope.addQuery = function() {
        console.log($scope.newQueryInput);
        console.log($scope);

        if (typeof $scope.newQueryInput != "undefined") {
            newQuery = { "keyword" : $scope.newQueryInput }
            $scope.queries.push(newQuery);
            $scope.newQueryInput = "";
        }
    };
    $scope.removeQuery = function(index) {
        $scope.queries.splice(index, 1);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done 3 fixes to your form:

1. Changed `$scope.queries = queries;` to `$scope.queries = [];` because queries is undefined
2. Added $event.preventDefault(); to submit handler so form will not be submitted.
3. Added check for empty string $scope.newQueryInput !== ""

And now it works with Enter key or button click.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.3/angular.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="plunker">
        <ul ng-controller="QueryCtrl">
            <li ng-repeat="query in queries">
                <i class="fa fa-trash onhover alignleft" title="delete query" ng-click="removeQuery($index)"></i>
                <a href="#">{{query.keyword}}</a>
            </li>
            <li class="addnew">
                <form ng-submit="addQuery($event)" action="">
                    <input type="text" ng-model="newQueryInput" placeholder="Add new query"/>
                    <input type="submit" />
                </form>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </body>
    <script>
    var app = angular.module('plunker', []).controller('QueryCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.queries = [];
        
        $scope.addQuery = function($event) {
            $event.preventDefault();

            if (typeof $scope.newQueryInput != "undefined"
                && $scope.newQueryInput !== "") {
                newQuery = { "keyword" : $scope.newQueryInput }
                $scope.queries.push(newQuery);
                $scope.newQueryInput = "";
            }
        };
        
        $scope.removeQuery = function(index) {
            $scope.queries.splice(index, 1);
        }
    }]);
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: `$event.preventDefault();` throws `TypeError: Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined` - it seems that $event is undefined, although I changed the form attribute to `ng-submit="addQuery($event)"`

Comment: I just noticed that you are including a newer version of AngularJS. I was using 1.0.0 from a probably outdated tutorial.